# Derogative vs Offensive

Tags: meaning, american-english

Is a derogative comment an offensive comment?

To what extent are these two words synonyms?

Comment: Did you mean *derogatory*?

Comment: Derogative and derogatory are close synonyms.

Comment: Only in AmE (which is why I have retagged it): the OED has 'tending to derogation' (a technical/legal term) as the only definition.

Comment: @TimLymington [Derogative](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/derogative?s=t) From old French.  Adj. - lessening; belittling; derogatory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Derogative comments ***can*** be offensive, depending on context - but they are certainly **not** synonyms. There can be a lot of overlap between the two, trying to explain the differences with examples:

***Derogative not offensive*** : Consider the example of 'housewife' given in MW [definition for derogative](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/derogative) - it might be 'belittling' or w/e (personally I disagree but it does have negative connotations for some people) but you can hardly say that calling someone a housewife is 'offensive'.

***Offensive not derogative*** : Some terms such as [cripple](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cripple) are recently considered offensive, with people preferring to substitute 'handicapped' or 'special needs' etc. as terms. However as a statement of fact it isn't derogative (you aren't belittling someone by pointing out they can't walk properly)

***Both derogative & offensive*** : See the [list of ethnic slurs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ethnic_slurs_by_ethnicity) on Wikipedia, most of them are both derogative (having some negative connotation) and offensive for various reasons to the target populace.

Answer (score 4):

They are not synonyms. A comment can be offensive in many ways, eg by using explicit sexual or profane language in an inappropriate setting, without it being derogatory to any one particular person or thing.

*Derogative* in Merriam-Webster:

> ...intended to make a person or thing seem of little importance or
>   value.

*Derogatory* seems to be more usual in BrE.

Comment: Ok but if I tried to make you seem of little importance or value, would you feel offended?

Comment: Potentially anyone could be offended - no one likes to be put down like that. But whether you react by bursting into tears, punching the offender, or calmly letting it wash over you is down to the individual. You say 'tried', which means it's deliberate and therefore more hurtful/annoying than if if someone thoughtlessly belittles you.

Comment: Here we go again with anonymous downvoters. The purpose for downvoting is 'This answer is not useful'. It might not be the best answer, it might not be worthy of an upvote, but can the downvoter please explain what is so wrong with it that it's considered 'not useful'? When I rule ELU it will all be different....

Answer (score 0):

Derogatory comments are demeaning (degrading) and are  offensive (most of the time), but not always. Many times derogatory names are used as terms of endearment, but there is a fine line. People may be offended even if the comment or name was not directed at them, specifically if the name is used to refer negatively to a group of people.

Answer (score 0):

*Derogative* is arrogant and condescending. *Offensive* is a wide open assault to one's sense of decency.