# Slang word for amputee

Tags: slang, colloquialisms

How do you refer (informally) to someone that is missing (1) one eye (2) a leg / foot or an arm / hand. ??

Am looking for something that I can use in a translated expression... For example...

We say in Spanish:

*The amputees like to meet up to scratch each other's backs...*

Comment: Adding your own research findings and word considerations enhances your question ... and its continuation.

Comment: related: [One word for “a one-eyed person”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/234639/one-word-for-a-one-eyed-person) and [Derogative vs Offensive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/162186/derogative-vs-offensive/162190#162190)

Comment: There are SO MANY possibilities for this.  You can use a word like disabled, injured, amputee(as you state in the title) and many others depending on the context for the sentence.  Are you referring to their physical condition, their ability to do something, their appearance, how they are perceived by society, how they are perceived by others with the same malady, how they are perceived by a someone with whom they are interacting in some specific matter...  All of these could create a lot of different words.

Answer (score 2):

**gimp** [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/gimp)

​

> 1. informal offensive an unpleasant or stupid person: I can't stand
>    that gimp.
>
> ​
>
> 2. US informal offensive a person with a physical disability,
>    especially one that affects someone's legs
>
> ​
>
> 3. US informal a limp (= a way of walking slowly and with difficulty
>    because of having an injured or painful leg or foot )
>
> ​
>
> 4. a person who gets sexual pleasure from being hurt or treated badly

Of the 4 senses of this word, #2 would fit this question.  Interesting that this registry list the senses 1 and 2 as offensive and senses 3 as informal and 4 without qualification.

**gimp**  a noun, is described in [The New Partridge Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English](https://books.google.com/books?id=bbcBCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA989&ots=PFwwwM5R9J&dq=gimp%20partridge%20dictionary&pg=PA989#v=onepage&q=gimp%20partridge%20dictionary&f=true)

as:

> a cripple